# MDX COUNT Number of Customers afected by a MDX query

Tags: count, ssas, mdx

I'm having a problem to get the count od a MDX query. I have a first query like this:

```
SELECT { [Measures].[Sale Amount] } ON COLUMNS,  
NON EMPTY FILTER (
    {[Customer].[Full Name].Children} * {[Report].[Name].Children}
    ,
    ([Measures].[Sale Amount] > 100) 
    AND (([Report].[Name].&[Report1]) OR ([Report].[Name].&[Report2])) 
    AND ([Report].[Name].&[Report3]) 
) ON ROWS 
FROM [Default]
```

This will display the data that I need. But from here I need to know how many customers are within this result. For that I have the following MDX query

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.X AS Exists(
    [Customer].[Customer Key].Children, 
    FILTER (
    {[Customer].[Full Name].Children} * {[Report].[Name].Children}
    ,
    ([Measures].[Sale Amount] > 100) 
    AND (([Report].[Name].&[Report1]) OR ([Report].[Name].&[Report2])) 
    AND ([Report].[Name].&[Report3]) 
), 'Customer').Count
SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM [Default]
```

(the filter area of both queries is the same)

This last query always returns 0 results. I know that there are customers should be customers affected by this query Can any one give me a tip of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to get the count of all customer keys for each single customer full name, or just one count across all customer full names returned by the filter?

Comment: Hi FrankPl. I want a customer count across all the results from the filter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the count of the filter:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.X AS
     FILTER (
        {[Customer].[Full Name].Children} * {[Report].[Name].Children}
        ,
        ([Measures].[Sale Amount] > 100) 
        AND (([Report].[Name].&[Report1]) OR ([Report].[Name].&[Report2])) 
        AND ([Report].[Name].&[Report3]) 
    ).Count
SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM [Default]
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks againg FrankPl. That may work, the only problem is that as soon as I put several condition on the filter it stop working, leaving only ([Measures].[Sale Amount] > 100) it works fine, but as soon as I add Attributes from a Dimension it returns no data. Am I missing something?